# Usage of an Interface in onMessage Method (Java EE + JMS)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jms

I have a problem. I have a Consumer-Class, with an Interface, which is declared as @EJB:

> ```
> /**
>  * A downloader
>  */
> @EJB
> private IDownloader downloader;
> ```

I have also an onMessage-Method, which looks similar to that:

> ```
> @Override public void onMessage(Message message) {
> try {
>     ObjectMessage messageObject = (ObjectMessage) message;
>     CSVMessage csvMessage = (CSVMessage) messageObject.getObject();
>     downloader.download(csvMessage.getUrl());
> } catch (JMSException e) {
>     throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
> }
> }
> ```

When executing, I get the following message:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-9332852)) javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Not Found
ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (Thread-3 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-9332852)) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component Downloader for method public abstract java.lang.String com.packagename(java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Not Found
```

Any hints how to handle an Interface in an onMessage method?

Comment: you'll need to give more details around your code snippets, but it looks like the MDB (onMessage) isn't able to find the EJB (downloader). does this error show on deployment or on execution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting a NullPointerException at

```
downloader.download(csvMessage.getUrl());
```

Try to inject the EJB like this (eg: on Consumer-Class constructor)

```
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContex();
    this.downloader = ctx.lookup("replace_with_ejb_jndi");
} catch (NamingException e) {
  //do something
}
```